# Using Bitbucket App Password in WebStorm

Tags: bitbucket, webstorm

I'm working on a project in WebStorm that's hooked up to Bitbucket for version control. Every once in a while I get a prompt to log into my repository and there is link on the bottom suggesting I use a Bitbucket app password. I have an app password on Bitbucket, but can't find anything on the web about how to integrate WebStorm with the app password.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your repository is at https://bitbucket.org/username/repo.git then the username field is to be filled with the username part in the URL and the password is your created app password.

Comment: Had to implement this today since bitbucket now prevents authentication without using the app password. You can force the credentials dialog to show up by navigating to Preferences > Version Control > Git, and scroll down to the bottom and uncheck "Use credential helper".

Answer (score 3):

Instead of typing your account username and password in the dialog, type your app password's id in the username field and your app password's password in the password field.

[image]

Comment: That solution is not working for me. The repositories username is working. Bitbucket has no more App Password IDs.